# Why I must use jQuery definition instead of $?

Tags: jquery, plugins, simplemodal

I'm a newbie in jQuery...

I've used one jQuery plugin (Actually SimpleModal Plugin) in my page. It didn't work until I replace $ with jQuery!

```
$(document).ready(function() {    -->    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

It is working now, but I still have a problem! I want to close this modal window by click on my cancel button on the page. 
In the manual of SimpleModal have been said: "you can programmatically close the currently opened dialog by calling $.modal.close();" but it doesn't work for me. I replaced the "$" with "jQuery" but doesn't work.

I want to know why I must use jQuery definition?! and what I must do in this situation?!

P.S. 
This code worked properly when clicking the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#cancelID').click(function() {
            alert ("test");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code doesn't proper action:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#cancelID').click(function() {
            $.modal.close();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your time and helping others.

Comment: Are you using a jQuery dialog modal? if so, then a statement like: $(this).dialog('close'); would work in the modal code associated with the button.

Comment: @Mark - Except for he's using SimpleModal and not the jQuery UI Dialog...

Comment: @Mark: Thank you for your comment, I will test your suggestion, thanks ;)

@Eric: Thanks for your great plug-in, it's perfect ;) 

@All: I actually can't close the modal page by my button, instead I try to use its default close button... It worked successfully, but I love to learn how I can use my cancel button!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you still call it as a property on the jQuery object, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#cancelID').click(function() {
        jQuery.modal.close();
    });
});
```

Or use `$` inside the `ready` function (it's passed as the first parameter) like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#cancelID').click(function() {
        $.modal.close();
    });
});
```

As for why doesn't `$` just work?  Look in your code for [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) or [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).  This function releases control of the `$` so it's no longer the same as `jQuery`, usually this is for other libraries to have control of it, Prototype for example.

Comment: Thank you really much Nick... I tested your codes but unfortunately they didn't work... :(

But your explain and links about my question was really useful! thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should know the following:

1. jQuery defines only one global (document/window level) variable: **`$`**
2. Other libraries might be using the `$` global variable *(example: Prototype)*
3. Thus, if you're using another JS library **along with** jQuery, jQuery plays it nicely by offering the `noConflict` function. This function basically re-assigns the value of $ to the other library and use the `jQuery` keyword instead.
4. jQuery plugins already use the `jQuery` keyword, assuming that you might be using other libraries.

Comment: I'm learning many thing from you guys! thanks for useful answers ;) You explained it really clear, you are a great teacher!

Answer (score 0):

One potentially useful trick I found was, you can surround your $-using jQuery code with

```
(function($){

...

})(jQuery)
```

And all your $ signs will work again, without any need to change them individually to "jQuery".

Comment: As your advice I changed my code to this:

(function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#cancelID').click(function() {
                $.modal.close();
            });
        });
})(jQuery)

but again it can't close my modal form! Anyway, thanks for your time and your answer ;)